# How to disable implicit conversion to pointer-to-void in parameter overload resolution?

Tags: c++

### Motivation

Suppose that I have a function taking `void *` as an argument. I'd like to overload this function to other pointer types, but disable the implicit conversion from other pointer types to `void *` (and only that conversion). I still want the implicit conversion to base class types to succeed.

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
class Other {};
class Stream {};

Stream & operator<<(Stream&, void *);
Stream & operator<<(Stream&, const Base*);

void test() {
  Stream str;
  Derived der;
  Other other;
  // I want the below to work
  str << (void*)&der;
  str << &der; // (&der) gets implicitly converted to const Base*
  // But I want this to fail at either compile or link time
  str << &other;
}
```

### The Pedantic Pointer Idiom

Prevention of implicit conversion to pointer-to-void has been called a [Pedantic Pointer Idiom](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1553) by Matt Wilson, and it's useful when implementing type-safe streams and logging.

His implementation uses a template facade that dispatches to am implementation with a dummy pointer-to-pointer argument. This leverages the fact that `Foo**` is not implicitly convertible to `void**`. I'd like to avoid the overhead of the second argument.

```
template <typename T> Stream & operator<<(Stream & s, T const* t)  
{  
  return dump(s, t, &t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving it is to specialize the operator for the void type. That way there's no need to declare `Stream & dump(Stream &, void const*)`, thus side-stepping the problem.

```
template <typename T> Stream & operator<<(Stream & s, T const* t)  
{  
  return dump(s, t);
} 

template <> Stream & operator<<(Stream & s, void const * t)
{
  // implement the dump here
  return s;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the template will also match things like `int*`, which don't have a `dump` function, and for which you want the conversion to `void*`.

Comment: @JamesKanze The whole point is that I only want the `operator<<` to work for the types I explicitly wrote `dump` for (and the derived types, if any). I certainly do not want a `void*` dump to be called for `int*` (and it won't be). Heck, in my code I simply leave the specialization for `void const *` declared but undefined. In my case, dumping of a `void *` to the stream makes absolutely no sense and would be an error.